# Script doesn't work on elements loaded with infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm using this script on my tumblr page, which gives posts different random text colors:

```
function get_random_color() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
return color;}
$(function() {
$(".post").each(function() {
    $(this).css("color", get_random_color());
}); });
```

The thing is the script isn't working for elements loaded with infinite scrolling. Can anyone help me rewrite this code? I don't know how to write javascript sadly.

Comment: please post the ajax part in which you load other posts

Comment: How do you call/setup infinite scrolling (or is it a tumblrfeature)? And show us that as reference to please.

Comment: Is it working initially, but new elements aren't colored after you scroll?  When do initial infinite scrolling elements get added, before or after the script runs?

Comment: This is the website if it helps: http://co-op.co.il/
It works for elements on the first page, but any elements added don't run the script

Comment: Have you tried calling `get_random_color` within your `infinite_scroll` call when you grab the elements?

Comment: I haven't, can you tell me how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your blog's `main.js` script. You can call your custom function when you grab the new elements from another page. This is my proposed revision of your `main.js` file.

```
$(window).load(function () {
var $wall = $('#content');
$wall.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $wall.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isAnimated: false
    });
});
$wall.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '#pagination',
    nextSelector: '#pagination li a.pagination_nextlink',
    itemSelector: '.post',
    loadingImg: "http://static.tumblr.com/kwz90l7/bIdlst7ub/transparent.png",
    loadingText: " ",
    donetext: " ",
    bufferPx: 100,
    debug: false,
    errorCallback: function () {
        $('#infscr-loading').animate({
            opacity: .8
        }, 2000).fadeOut('normal');
    }
}, function (newElements) {
    var $newElems = $(newElements);
    $newElems.hide();
    $newElems.each(function(value){
        value.css("color", get_random_color());
    });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $wall.masonry('appended', $newElems, {
            isAnimated: false,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 900,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        }, function () {
            $newElems.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            deeplinking: false,
            default_width: 600,
            default_height: 550,
            allow_resize: true,
        });
    });
});
$('#content').show(500);
});

function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
         color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
 }
```

What I've done is add your `get_random_color` function and called it from within the Infinite Scroll call to add a custom color to each of the elements in `$newElems` so really, all I've done is taken your code and integrated it differently than what you were trying to do, which wasn't working. This should, theoretically, work. If it doesn't or you have questions, let me know.

Comment: Hey, thanks! When I tried to use this code in main.js, it caused the infinite scrolling to stop working