# infinite scroll : js code inside itemSelector

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I've implemented [infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) on my wordpress. Content (title, images, rte, etc.) for each articles are perfectly loaded, except their own js code.

Let me explain : 
I've put some JS code that I can't call outside because it's using php variables specific to each article.
I know I could/should use the infinite-scroll callback and use a global JS for articles, but I couldn't use the php variables :(

To summarize, how my JS can be read by infinite scroll ? Is this the fact that infinite scroll is working in AJAX ? Is there another method / plugin ?

Thank you all !

For example :
Inside my looped article, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('test');
</script>
```

It is well called for the first article, but not for the ones loaded by infinite scroll.

This case is pretty similar : [Script doesn't work on elements loaded with infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513337/script-doesnt-work-on-elements-loaded-with-infinite-scrolling) but as I said, I can't do a main.js file because I'm using specific php vars for each article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, solved by finally made a main js file, and using data-XX for my php vars :)